# Extended inline assembly breaking the function

Tags: linux, x86-64, intel, inline-assembly, att

The environment is x86_64 on Linux. I am trying to speed up some calculations in a foo function by writing an inline assembly. I want to pass 4 chars into a 32-bit register and do calculations for one time instead of doing the calculations separately for the 4 chars. Variables a,b, and c are pointers to 4 chars.

This is the working code that allows me to get the correct calculation results but it is way slower than the original C code. I am calculating the 4 chars separately.

```
__asm__(
     "lea (%%esi, %%eax, 2), %%eax \n\t"
     //... more calculations for a.x and a.x
     : "=g" (a.x), "=g" (b.x)
     : "r" (b.x), "r" (a.x), "r" (c.x)
     :"%edx"
);
__asm__(
     "lea (%%esi, %%eax, 2), %%eax \n\t"
     //... more calculations for a.y and b.y
     : "=g" (a.y), "=g" (b.y)
     : "r" (b.y), "r" (a.y), "r" (c.y)
     :"%edx"
);
__asm__(
     "lea (%%esi, %%eax, 2), %%eax \n\t"
     //... more calculations for a.b and a.c
     : "=g" (a.z), "=g" (b.z)
     : "r" (b.z), "r" (a.z), "r" (c.z)
     :"%edx"
);
```

Instead of passing the chars separately, I tried to pass in a, b, and c directly. I am not getting any segmentation fault but the outside function is completely messed up (not because of overflowing). I need to understand better about how pipelining and x86_64 works to improve performance. Any recommendation for the materials I should read?

Comment: You hard-code some register names, but then you tell the compiler it can pick any register for inputs with `"r"`, and any register or a memory location for the outputs with `"=g"`.  Obviously it picked registers other than `RSI` and `RAX`.  (And BTW, you should never use an address-size override prefix with LEA, it's pointless.  Just use `lea (%%rsi, %%rax, 2), %eax` if you want 32-bit operand-size.)

Comment: *I am trying to speed up some calculations in a foo function by writing an inline assembly*  It looks like that was your first mistake.  x86-64 guarantees that SSE2 SIMD is available.  You can probably use that via intrinsics to operate on 16 chars at a time, loading them in chunks of 4 if necessary (ideally use `_mm_loadu_si128`).  But see also [C++ code for testing the Collatz conjecture faster than hand-written assembly - why?](//stackoverflow.com/q/40354978) for more about how to write efficient asm, or better how to write C that can *compile* to efficient asm.

Comment: While it is clear that this is GCC, don't think that inline assembly is the same for each compiler or platform. So next time, please state the compiler too, as a tag, and the platform (Linux, BSD, Windows, Mac, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! I am using Linux as the platform.